# How to clear history of an activity when i use onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I am capturing multiple pictures using camera intent in activity (say Activity B). So `onactivityresult` is not called if I add `android:nohistory="true"` or `android:launchmode="singleInstance"`. Then, may I know do I clear this activity history in my application. Because whenever I hit the back button from previously opened activity (say Activity A) this same activity keep calling.. I know that I can able call this activity with in Activity A but I am calling this Activity B by non-activity which extends `PagerAdapter` for fullscreenimagedisplay.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(resultCode)
    {
    case RESULT_CLOSE_ALL:
        setResult(RESULT_CLOSE_ALL);
        finish();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Let me know if this code may help you or not.

Comment: No predefined RESULT_CLOSE_ALL. Then how do i predict the resultCode value. i think, it may vary know. am i right?

Comment: Thank u so much. it's worked just calling finish(); nothing else.

Comment: Your welcome. If you have any issue feel free to ask me.